# jQuery Date Validation (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to validate a date using [this script](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) in the format of YYYY-MM-DD, but I can't seem to get it working perfectly. With the regular expression I'm using, it allows for users to enter 10 numbers without dashes, instead of 8 with dashes in the correct places. Is there a way to modify my script to fix this?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("date", function(date, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || date.match(/^[-0-9]{10}$/);
            }, "Please specify a valid date");
```

Comment: By using a differnent regex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a wrong regex.

You can use this one instead :

`^\d{4}-((0\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\d)|3[01])$`

So it would be :

```
return this.optional(element) || date.match(/^\d{4}-((0\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\d)|3[01])$/);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Even matches for 1-12 months and 1-31 days :) I'll accept as soon as it'll let me.

Comment: Notice that it won't check specific months for length (eg. 31st Feb) but it's a bit difficult and long with regex :) And if you want only 19XX/20XX years, you can change `\d{4}` to `(19|20)\d{2}`

Comment: date.match is returning null to me, shouldnt it return `true` or `false`

Comment: \r3g3x\.match returns all the matches in the string, not true or false.

Comment: what would be the regex if I want dd-MM-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

This would validate the exact format with dashes in the correct place.

```
/^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/
```

Fuller validation to ensure sensible year/month/day values could be

```
/^(19|20)\d\d-(0\d|1[012])-(0\d|1\d|2\d|3[01])$/
```