# jQuery date validation - format and range

Tags: jquery, validation, date, jquery-validate

I have a requirement where I will have 2 date fields (`to`, `from`) and needs to validate them:

- whether they are mm/dd/yyyy format
- both the dates are in particular range
- as the name suggests `to` should always be greater than `from`
- both fields become mandatory as soon as i enter any one of these

what will be the best way to implement the same, am using jquery validation api

**Note**: I did read about format validation on some of the links like [jQuery Date Validation (YYYY-MM-DD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544844/jquery-date-validation-yyyy-mm-dd) but these doesnt ensure that its a valid date I may end up entering something like `02/31/2999`

i tried

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("DateFormat", function(value, element) {
    var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    var values = value.split("/");
    return this.optional(element) || (value.test(date_regex) && (new Date(values[2], values[0], values[1])));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have handled pretty much exactly this problem.  What you need to do is create a series of validation rules.
First, you give the dates some sort of appropriate class attributes - "fromDate" and "toDate", say.

- One that uses a regular expression to make sure that they're in the right format
- one that date-converts that using the javascript Date object, and makes sure that they're in the right range.
- one for the from date, that knows how to find the to date (generally handled by going up a level or two, and then running `.find('input.toDate'))` or similar on it, and compares them.
- Another, reversed, for the to date.
- One that returns true if both are empty, but false if one is empty and the other full

Then you assign the appropriate rules to the appropriate classes with `jQuery.validate.addClassRules()`.

Put all of that code before you set up your validator on the form in question, and it should work just fine.  Syntax is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: i did tried some solutions, pls check the updated questions. Still not able to find full proof method to check for valid date in mm/dd/yyyy method. any help pls

Comment: If you're having problems with the Feb 31 issue, using the javascript Date() object still helps.  Once you've done the rough check with your regexp (as above), you throw it into a date constructor.  Then you ask the date for a month (remember that days and months are 0-based in the Date object - makes it a bit trickier, but is still doable) and compare it to the printed month on the date.  if you get a "feb 31" or similar, the Date constructor will cause it to roll over into the next month, and the months won't line up properly.  If you have some other problem, please explain mroe clearly.

Answer (score 0):

added followign validation methods

```
// jquery validation method to validate date format
jQuery.validator.addMethod("DateFormat", function(value, element) {
    var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    var comp = value.split('/');
    var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
    var date = new Date(y,m,d);
    return this.optional(element) || (date_regex.test(value) && date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() == m && date.getDate() == d);
});
//jquery validation method to validate date range
jQuery.validator.addMethod("DateToFrom", function(value, element, arg0, arg1) {
    var comp = value.split('/');
    var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
    var currentEltdate = new Date(y,m,d);

    comp = $("#"+arg0).val().split('/');
    m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
    var otherEltDate = new Date(y,m,d);

    var lowerDate, upperDate;
    if(arg1 == true){//current element should be lower date
        lowerDate = currentEltdate;
        upperDate = otherEltDate;
    }else{
        lowerDate = otherEltDate;
        upperDate = currentEltdate;
    }
    return this.optional(element) || (lowerDate <= upperDate);
});
// jquery validation method to validate date range
jQuery.validator.addMethod("DateRange", function(value, element, arg0, arg1) {
    var comp = arg0.split('/');
    var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
    var startDate = new Date(y,m,d);

    comp = arg1.split('/');
    m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
    var endDate = new Date(y,m,d);

    comp = value.split('/');
    m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
    d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
    y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
    var date = new Date(y,m,d);

    return this.optional(element) || ((startDate <= date) && (date <= endDate));
});
```